# How to show what privileges a user has on a database in Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have tried to write a script that should show me who has privileges on a database and what are these privileges. My problem is that the script is outputting that everyone has all the privileges `connect, create, temp` on all the databases, however that is not true.

My script is like this:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
db_r record;
BEGIN
     FOR db_r IN
      select db.datname, rl.rolname, case 
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect, create, temp') then
                           cast ('connect, create, temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect, create') then
                           cast ('connect, create' AS pg_catalog.text)
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect, temp') then
                           cast ('connect, temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'create, temp') then
                           cast ('create, temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect') then
                           cast ('connect' AS pg_catalog.text)
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'create') then
                           cast ('create' AS pg_catalog.text)
                           when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'temp') then
                           cast ('temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                         end privilege
      from pg_roles rl
        cross join pg_database db
      where rl.rolcanlogin
        and db.datallowconn
        and db.datname not in ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')
      order by db.datname, rl.rolname
        LOOP
         IF db_r.privilege is not null then
         RAISE NOTICE '% has % privilege on database %;',
                 db_r.rolname, db_r.privilege, db_r.datname;
         END IF;
        END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

There must surely be something wrong in the logics of my script, but I cannot see it. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: It is working on my comp. Do you have some other database than postgres, template1 and template0?

Comment: Yes, I have other databases than these three I have showed here. In fact, in my script I exclud these three and include only the other databases I need, but I have tested with them and only with these three and I always get the output that all users and roles have all privileges to all databases. I wonder if it is not inheriting it from some roles, but I am not sure if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer by myself.

The problem was in the way I built my case statement.

I have corrected it and it is like this now:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
db_r record;
BEGIN
     FOR db_r IN
      select db.datname, rl.rolname, case 
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect')
                                       and has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'create')
                                       and has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'temp') then
                                       cast ('connect, create, temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                                       
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect')
                                       and has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'create') then
                                       cast ('connect, create' AS pg_catalog.text)
                                       
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect')
                                       and has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'temp') then
                                       cast ('connect, temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                                       
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'create')
                                       and has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'temp') then
                                       cast ('create, temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                                       
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'connect') then
                                       cast ('connect' AS pg_catalog.text)
                                       
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'create') then
                                       cast ('create' AS pg_catalog.text)
                                       
                                       when has_database_privilege(rl.rolname, db.datname, 'temp') then
                                       cast ('temp' AS pg_catalog.text)
                         end privilege
      from pg_roles rl
        cross join pg_database db
      where rl.rolcanlogin
        and db.datallowconn
        and db.datname not in ('postgres', 'template0', 'template1')
      order by db.datname, rl.rolname
        LOOP
         IF db_r.privilege is not null then
         RAISE NOTICE '% has % privilege on database %;',
                 db_r.rolname, db_r.privilege, db_r.datname;
         END IF;
        END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

The problem was that I was trying to test if a user/role has more than one privilege on a database using one function call. To correct it, I had to call the function once for every privilege using the operator `and` in my case statement, in order to evaluate the case that a user/role has more than one privilege on a database.

Now the code shows the correct output: what privileges a user/role has on a database.